# pow() raising to floats

Tags: python, math

Why does raising to an integer expressed as a floating point number give different results to raising the same number in its integer form?

E.g.:

```
>>> pow(10,25)%195
10L
>>> pow(10,25.0)%195
64.0
```

I've tried using [mpmath's `power()`](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/powers.html#power) instead, but get the exact same numbers - and error - as the second form.

How can I raise to very large non-integer powers and perform mod on them (e.g. steps taken to perform RSA-like logic using pure math) in Python?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Why do you need this? RSA does not use 
non-integer exponents.

Comment: @AnotherTest yes I was just looking at the form as was struck by how like RSA it was, *except* that I have a non-integer exponent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For integers, you can use the 3-argument form of pow:

```
pow(10, 25, 195)
```

Your problem here stems from loss of precision in floats. You need to use `decimal.Decimal`s here:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> pow(10, Decimal('25.0')) % 195
Decimal('10')
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, because floats in Python are [IEEE754 floats and have limited precision](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

```
>>> int(10**25.0)
10000000000000000905969664L
```

As you can see, the answer is close but incorrect.

> How can I raise to very large non-integer powers and perform mod on them (e.g. steps taken to perform RSA-like logic using pure math) in Python?

This is my suggestion using `x^(a+b) = x^a * x^b`:

```
def powmod_f(base, exponent, mod):
    return (pow(base, int(exponent), mod) * (base ** (exponent % 1))) % mod
```

This only works with an integer base however, if your base is a float as well you're going to have to implement a powmod algorithm yourself.